# Show that $(x+ \sqrt{x})^n$ is arbitrarily close to an integer for $x \leq 3$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

So basically I want to show two things, firstly that $$(2+\sqrt{2})^n$$ approaches an integer as $n$ gets large. And secondly that this is only true for $$\lim_{n \to \infty }(x+\sqrt{x})^n, x \leq 3.$$

To show the first one, I tried to expand the expression using the binomial theorem. Arguing that the binomial coefficients are positive integers so it remains to show that a sum of $2$'s to some power of $n$ is an integer there I'm pretty much stuck...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $(2+\sqrt2)^n+(2-\sqrt2)^n$ is an integer

Comment: Prove that $(2+\sqrt2)^n+(2-\sqrt2)^n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: No, this property is only there for certain algebraic numbers. Check out [Pisot-Vijayaraghavan numbers:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number) 
$2+\sqrt{2}$ is a P-V number, other example includes: $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$, $1+\sqrt{2}$. So I don't think this can be generalized like this.

Comment: The question is wrong. $(2 + \sqrt 2)^n$ does not approach any integer. It grows to infinity. Perhaps you should say the fractional part $\{(2 + \sqrt 2)^n\}$ approaches an integer. But then there are certainly other $x$ satisfying the same property: $x = 4, 9, 16, \dots$.

Comment: @WhatsUp those can be categorized as trivial solutions. Also a good definition would be to look for numbers s.t $x^n-[x^n] \rightarrow 0$? Where $[x]$ being the rounding-to the greatest integer.

Comment: @Mourad Yes, that seems to be better.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: what is $(x+\sqrt{x})^n +(x-\sqrt{x})^n$? How big can $x$ get to ensure $(x-\sqrt{x})^n$ decays as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Is it true for all $x\le 3 $,, if we take, $x=3$ , then $(3-\sqrt{3})^{n}$ goes to $\infty$

Comment: It can be true for $x\le 2.61$

Comment: No, $3$ is too ambitious. You need $x-\sqrt{x}<1$.

Comment: I don't understand, whenever $x$ is irrationals and rational numbers other than the integers then how do this even work?

Comment: Then how can you say $(x+\sqrt{x})^{n}+(x-\sqrt{x})^{n}$ an integer?

Comment: @Alearner this is a necessary, not a sufficient condition. Your points are well-taken, but I decided to leave some details for OP.

Comment: I just wanna know,,,in your opinion,, is the op's question true for all irrationals and rational numbers other than integers? Because I don't see any of.

Comment: No; OP's question is only true for certain algebraic integers.

Answer (score 5):

This is called a Pisot number, consider $r=2+\sqrt{2}$ and its conjugate $\bar r=2-\sqrt{2}$

Notice that $|\bar r|<1$ so that $(\bar r)^n\to 0$.

Now let's have a polynomial with $r$ and $\bar r$ as roots $P(t)=(t-r)(t-\bar r)=t^2-4t+2$

This is also the characteristic equation of a linear recurrence relation $$u_{n+2}=4u_{n+1}-2u_n$$

Notice that if $u_0$ and $u_1$ are integers, then by induction $u_n$ is an integer for all $n$.

The general solutions are expressed as $$\alpha r^n+\beta \bar r^n$$

Initial terms are $\begin{cases}u_0=\alpha+\beta\\u_1=2(\alpha+\beta)+\sqrt{2}(\alpha-\beta)\end{cases}$

So let's get rid of the square root (need to be an integer), for instance with $\alpha=\beta=1$.

We have proved that $r^n+\bar r^n\in\mathbb Z$ and since $\bar r^n\to 0$ then $r^n$ gets close to an integer as $n$ goes to infinity.

---

You can do it with any $r=x+\sqrt{x}$ as long as :

- $|x-\sqrt{x}|<1$, which implies $x<\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ (so $x=3$ do not work)
- we also need $P(t)$ to be a polynomial with integer coefficients $\begin{cases}2x\in\mathbb Z\\x^2-x\in\mathbb Z\end{cases}$ in order to make induction for $u_n\in\mathbb Z$ work.

But this condition pretty much restricts $x$ to $0,1,2$

---

Let $f(x)=x-\sqrt{x}$ then $f'(x)=1-\frac 1{2\sqrt{x}}$

So $f$ has a minimum in $x=\frac 14$ (i.e. $f'(x)=0$) whose value is $f(\frac 14)=-\frac 12$, which solve the case $f(x)>-1$.

Now $f(x)<1\iff (x-1)<\sqrt{x}$ but since $x\ge 0$ (domain of $f$) we don't loose equivalence squaring this inequality.

Thus $(x-1)^2<x\iff x^2-3x+1<0$ solving the quadratic leads to $x$ between the roots $\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$, but we are not interested in the lower one since it is $>\frac 14$ so $f\nearrow$ there.

$$|x-\sqrt{x}|<1\iff 0\le x<\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: Consider my doubt. Take $r=\frac{5}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}$, we can see $\left|\overline{r}\right|<1$. But I can't see $r^{n}-\left[r^{n}\right]$ tending to $0$.

Comment: @Mourad you're right, I was careless, edited now.

Comment: What about the irrationals?

Comment: $2x\in\mathbb Z$ means $x=n/2$... Of course other $r$ works like $r=\frac {1+\sqrt{5}}2$ but they are not of the form $x+\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Thanks for this! Could I ask how you made the implication on the inequality on of x to be $x< \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$? :)

Comment: @JohnGreger I edited to detail this part at the end.